# JavaFX packager - can the name of the package icon be specified?

Tags: javafx, javapackager

For a couple of years, I have been releasing updates to a modest app on a yearly basis -- just before the summer swim league starts up.

In the past, I have specified the various icons (volume, app, etc.) by placing them in the `package/macosx/` folder. The filenames, `MyApp-volume.icns` etc., matched the `<fx:application name="MyApp" .../>` and everything worked just fine.

But starting with this year's build and deployment, the app's name will contain the year -- i.e., `MyApp 2016`. However, I don't want to be changing the icon filenames each year; I would like to keep them as they are (`MyApp-volume.icns`, `MyApp.icns`).

Is there a way to tell the Java packager to use a specific icon filename, one that is different from that of the app name or title? (I have looked at Oracle docs, but I don't see anything.)

Comment: There is no way to do what I want to do. javapackager doesn't allow such flexibility. I have resorted to running the JavaFX Ant tasks to create the DMG. Then I mount it and use Disk Utility to create a sparsebundle, copy the app folder from the mounted DMG, change the app and other associated names to include the year; create a sparsebundle, and do all the manual stuff to create a new DMG (see SO: "How to create a dmg file for a .app for mac.?").  ... (to be continued in next comment) ...

Comment: ... Since the app is used by both Mac and Windows users, I use equivalent tools and manual steps on the Windows side. ... Tedious, but it gets the job done once a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my first comment to my question, javapackager doesn't have an option to do this.

Here's the solution that I worked out:

1. Create a new folder at the same level as the folder `package` (this doesn't refer to Java `package` but to [Custom Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGJHGDG)). Name the new folder `package-base`.
2. Move the `macosx` and `windows` folders from `package` to `package-base`. (I don't produce an executable for Linux because none of my users use Linux.) Now, the `package` folder is empty.
3. In my build script, I added a step which, for every build that produces a "self-contained application package" (Oracle's terminology), cleans the `package` folder, and then copies the contents of `package-base` to `package`.
4. The files are renamed as they are copied to include the desired wording -- in my case, that means the year is appended to the filename. For example, `MyApp-volume.icns` when copied is renamed `MyApp-2018-volume.icns`.

Here are the relevant Gradle snippets:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
...
def getYear() {
    new Date().format('yyyy')
}
...
ext {
    ...
    year = getYear()
    appNameBase = "MyApp"
    appName = appNameBase + " " + year
    ...
}
...
task macCleanPackage {
    doLast {
        if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX()) {
            delete fileTree(dir: "./package/macosx", include: "*.*")
        }
    }
}

task macCopyAndRenamePackageResources {
    dependsOn macCleanPackage

    doLast {
        if (OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX()) {
            def toDir = "./package/macosx"
            copy {
                from './package-base/macosx'
                into "${toDir}"
                include "*${appNameBase}*.*"
                rename { String fileName -> fileName.replace("$appNameBase", "${appName}") }
            }
            ant.replaceregexp(file: "${toDir}/${appName}-dmg-setup.scpt", match:"${appNameBase}", replace:"${appName}", flags:'g')
        }
    }
}

task windowsCleanPackage {
    doLast {
        if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
            delete fileTree(dir: "package/windows", includes: ["*.bmp", "*.ico", "*.iss"])
        }
    }
}

task windowsCopyAndRenamePackageResources {
    dependsOn windowsCleanPackage

    doLast {
        if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
            def toDir = "./package/windows"
            copy {
                from './package-base/windows'
                into "${toDir}"
                include "*${appNameBase}*.*"
                rename { String fileName -> fileName.replace("$appNameBase", "${appName}") }
            }
            // Replace app name in iss setup script to include year.
            def issFilename = "./package/windows/${appName}.iss"
            ant.replaceregexp(file: "${issFilename}", match: "${appNameBase}", replace: "${appName}", flags: "g")
            ant.replaceregexp(file: "${issFilename}", match: "AppCopyright=Copyright (C)", replace: "AppCopyright=Copyright (C) ${year}", byline: "on")
            ant.replaceregexp(file: "${issFilename}", match: "AppVersion=", replace: "AppVersion=${year} build ${buildNumber}", byline: "on")
            ant.replaceregexp(file: "${issFilename}", match: "OutputBaseFilename=.*", replace: "OutputBaseFilename=${appName}-(build ${buildNumber})", byline: "on")
        }
    }
}
```

I don't just change filenames.

For the OS X release, `ant.replaceregexp` is used to modify the app's name in the custom AppleScript file.

For the Windows release, `ant.replaceregexp` is used extensively to replace version numbers, copyright, as well as the application's name (including the year) in the InnoSetup configuration file.

It may seem like a lot of extra work, but once the script is written, it just works.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Bicon=<path to icon relative to project resourses>
```

is this what you looking for?

or you could just add it to your main app `Stage`.

hope it is usefull

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I'm looking for. My question is related to using javapackager in an ANT build, using the JavaFX Ant tasks. Please see my comments to my own question above.